# Why cant docker accept the read command in my bash script?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-run

I am having a specific issue when trying to execute the docker run command on an image I have created.

I have ran the spellchecker for my scrip and know I can improve the style by using double quotes- but frankly this does not effect my script from running so please refrain for commenting on this at the moment.

See the full scrip below

```
#!/bin/bash
echo File Finder
echo what directory would you like to find?
read -r User
echo $User
COMMAND_DIRECTORY="/c/Users/HansPeterJonasHogh-J/dev/repos/${User}"
echo $COMMAND_DIRECTORY

if [ -d $COMMAND_DIRECTORY ]
then 
    echo "The $COMMAND_DIRECTORY exists"
    cd $COMMAND_DIRECTORY
    ls
    echo "This is the number of files you have"
# list all files and count
    ls -1 | wc -l
#function to loop through all files and copy into folder
    ls -lx
echo "What type of file you want sorted "
read FILE_EXT
echo $FILE_EXT
echo "What name would you like the folder called"
read USER_FOLDER
ECHO $USER_FOLDER

    for file in $COMMAND_DIRECTORY/*
    do
        if [[ "$file" == *$FILE_EXT ]]
        then
            mkdir -p ${USER_FOLDER}
            mv $file ${USER_FOLDER}
        fi
    done;

#echo what file you want to search for
#function loop through folder and find file
else 
    echo "The $COMMAND_DIRECTORY does not exist"
fi
```

The terminal output is this:

```
$ docker run filefind
File Finder
what directory would you like to find?

/c/Users/XYZ/dev/repos/
': not a valid identifierd: `User
file-find.sh: line 27: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'ile-find.sh: line 27: `    do
```

Previously I have copied everything into notepad++, edit, EOL conversion and selected Unix which has worked fine (my understanding this has something to do with docker and windows not being inherently compatible).

In the past I have parsed arguments in the terminal while executing the docker run command- however, this time round I want the user to be asked the questions first before they type hence the necessity for Read.

I hope this makes sense- and would love to get the answer but explanation as-well.

Comment: Use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to scan your script

Comment: seems like your script is written in DOS format. use tools like `dos2unix` to convert it to UNIX format.

Comment: The `$'\r'`s make it unambiguous that somehow DOS newlines slipped in; perhaps you missed the save-as-UNIX step recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run docker in “interactive mode”:

```bash
docker run -it filefind
```

Otherwise, the stdin of you script (inside the container) is connected to /dev/null instead of your terminal.